# How to center Input value with CSS

Tags: css, input, css-selectors

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php some-phpcode ?>" class="btn btn-link btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"/> 


div#inviaAzione input {
    background-color: #cdac81;
    color: #555;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 34px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    max-width: 75px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I center the word inside the button? Thanks for help!

Comment: You're using `text-align: center;` and that should do it, if the button is wide enough.

Comment: I can't share an image, but the Value text is centered on the bottom of the button. And I don't understand why

Comment: I see, perhaps that's due to a `vertical-align`? Check out [that CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Answer (score -1):

By default, HTML `input` element itself center the texts for you which you wish to put on button,

No need of even `text-align` attribute.